# I am getting ClasscastException

Tags: android, exception

I am implementing the google analytics in my android app. While accessing the Application class from mainactivity the following error is coming:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gaa/com.example.gaa.Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.gaa.GAApp
```

I am calling application class from activity class by given code:

```
((GAApplication)getApplication()).getTracker(GAApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've specified to use the `GAApplication` class in your `AndroidManifest`:

```
<!-- ... -->
<application
    android:name=".GAApplication">

<!-- ... -->

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your activity extends `GAApplication` class, and you need to specify you custom application class in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<application android:name=".GAApplication">

</application>
```